# Ajax error message can't accept parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the ID provided when the ajax-call is called to the error message but when I do it this way, the error message gets displayed even if no error message is returned through ajax (likepost_XML.php):

```
function like(commentid){

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'likepost_XML.php',
                data: { 
                    comment_id: escape(commentid)

                },
                success:  successlike,
                error: errormsga(commentid)
        });
}
```

And this is the Error function:

```
function errormsga(commentid)
{               
    console.log(":didn't work bro");
    $("#"+commentid).css({"color":"red"});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling errormsga instead of setting an error callback function. Wrap the call in a function expression.

```
error: function(){
    errormsga(commentid);
}
```